# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The status code returned from the server was: 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

My error is

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

I have an `UpdatePanel`, and a `GridView` in it, and several `TextBox`es on my webpage.In my gridview there are product informations, when I set the `SelectedIndex` of my gridview as -1 for the start.

I run the code, and select a product from the gridview, it works fine.Then I click to another product on the gridview(meaning the selected index is changed) then I get the error at the top of my question.

A day ago, Infragistics tabs were used in this webpage for `Tabs`, this error wasn't appearing, I am using Ajax `TabContainer` now but I can't seem to handle this error.I tried adding  `ValidateRequest="false"` to my Page directive but that didn't work out.

Any ideas?Anybody encountered with this kind of error and solved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may encounter with the same problem and suffer from it.

For the idea to solve the problem check [ValidateRequest page directive](http://forums.asp.net/p/1506225/3575891.aspx).
Well that is where I get the information about innerHTML-inner Text and HTMLEncode-HTMLDecode thing.
Then I used `Server.HtmlEncode();` for every textboxes I have on that webpage.An example

```
UrunNoTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode("");
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, it is an UpdatePanel problem in your page, here is the solution set EnablePartialRendering to false in the ScriptManager

I think it may help somebody

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes when you have a control registered as an AsyncPostbackTrigger in multiple update panels.

Try adding the following right after the script manager declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

     function EndRequestHandler(sender, args){

        if (args.get_error() != undefined){

            args.set_errorHandled(true);

        }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

change target platform of solution to 3.5

GO solution > Right Click > Property Pages > BUILD > TARGET FRAMEWORK